# Search with no results - can I display a custom text/message?

Tags: 2013, search-results

If a SharePoint 2013 Search does have no results, the following text is displayed:

> Preference for results in English   - Choose your search language.
>
> Nothing here matches your search
>
> Suggestions
>   •Make sure all words are spelled correctly
>   •Try different search terms
>   •Try more general search terms
>   •Try fewer search terms
>   •Try these tips for searching

How can I customize this text?

Answer (score 7):

You need to change Search Display Template. Search Results web part uses the "Control_SearchResults.html" display template that is available under the Master Page Library/Display Templates/Search.

1. Download a copy of that template (preferably, if you don't want to change the ootb one)
2. Open the file in Notepad (or any other text editor)
3. Replace the following line - "var emptyMessage = ctx.ClientControl.get_emptyMessage();" (in my environment it's line no. 347) with the text you want to be shown.
4. Save the file, upload it back to Master Page Library/Display Templates/Search folder, check it in. A .js file with the same name should be created automatically.
5. If you used a different name for your template, you will need to update search web part as well. Go to your page where the Search Result web part is, edit the Search results web part. Under the Display Templates section select the newly uploaded display template.

Comment: use SharePoint Designer to edit those files

Comment: Danny, it's a plain HTML file, any text editor will work. I prefer Notepad++ due to friendly syntax highlight.

Comment: Yes, but Designer doesn't need step 2 and helps with all the stuff from step 4. And Display Templates (the code in HTML comments) do not have syntax highlighting in any editor because someone stupid at Microsoft decided to put code in HTML comments

Comment: I prefer Notepad++ as well. I encourage the download/upload approach so you don't overwrite the original files.

Comment: While not wrong, you can also set the `EmptyMessage` on the Search Result Webpart. Export the WebPart, set the `EmptyMessage` upload the webpart again and replace the original. Also see https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/74589/how-do-you-set-the-default-empty-text-with-the-content-by-search-webpart/